# Coroutine not starting when loading from a different scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character selection screen that displays a confirmation screen and when selecting, a coroutine is started, a burst of particles fly into the screen and the new level is loaded - this is to delay the loading of the level so the particles can fill the screen.

This all works as intended when I test it by directly loading the scene (character selection) on the Unity editor, however, if I'm doing a full test and I come from (Start Screen) I can do everything and the debug says it is registering everything, however the particles don't show up and the loading doesn't execute.

Also, the console doesn't display any errors.

I've tried everything (Stop coroutine, using a `while(true)` ...) but can't figure out why it doesn't load. Code below:

The UI button has `LoadEloise()` as the method that gets triggered when clicking on it.

Code below:

Tried stopping coroutine right before activating it and also on Start, also making sure that the particle system is set to Active(false) before then being activated again.

```
IEnumerator DelayLoad() 
{
     heartExplosion[explosionNumber].gameObject.SetActive(true);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
     SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
}

public void LoadEloise() 
{
     sceneName = "Eloise"; 
     explosionNumber = 10; 

     StartCoroutine(DelayLoad());
}
```

Expected result: particle system is activated, covering the screen, and then after one second new scene is loaded.

This is a video showing the expected result, achieved by starting the test from the scene that hosts the coroutine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQAgzJ-HJB4&feature=youtu.be

Actual result: nothing, no errors, no particles nothing. The button is shown as pressed from the graphic point of view but nothing happens.

This is a video showing what happens when starting the code from the previous scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhEzi9Qjvg8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Add some debug statements check everythings value and whats going on

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you try to set breakpoints in order to see which line(s) get called? Also what do you mean by `by directly loading the scene`? From your code it is not visible why this shouldn't work ...

Comment: Is the object holding the script being active?

Comment: Thanks all, I did add Debug.Log to the console to see which lines are being called. It seems to stop right after activating the particle effect, however it's never displayed. which means that it goes into the coroutine but it never reaches the Load level part.

Comment: @Everts The object starts inactive, but when it is reached through the scene where the code is it activates it without a problem.

Comment: @derHugo thanks! I've added below links to two videos depicting the exact issue, hopefully that clarifies it. First one is what happens when I load the scene where the coroutine is (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQAgzJ-HJB4&feature=youtu.be) and the second one is what happens when I reach that same part but starting from the previous scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhEzi9Qjvg8&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your LoadEloise function even getting called?

If it was just a matter of the particles not getting displayed then it could have been a case of something like the canvas sorting order not being set properly for the particle system/container but if the subsequent scene loading is also not happening then you need to check two things first:

1. Add breakpoints/debug statements to follow the order of the execution of code and make sure that the correct functions are getting called in the order they are supposed to.
2. If all the functions are getting called and you don't see any error related to scene loading then it could be related to how the scene is set up when loaded externally. Add breakpoints/debug calls in the initialization function for the new scene to ensure that it has been loaded and is in place, make sure the position/scale of the content is not set to some weird value when the scene is loaded and check the hierarchy to locate the scene content in the editor window to make sure that the visual elements are set up properly.

Comment: Hi, so I've added breakpoints and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong. I also checked the scene when it was loaded from the previous scene and it contains everything. If I change the code so when clicking the button it takes you to the next scene it works fine, but if I try to delay it just to show the particle effect, either with a coroutine or an Invoke, it stops working but shows no error.

Comment: Managed to fix it!! The issue was with a line of code coming from a library that I had added to the main project, and that I forgot I was using in one button at the start, which changed the time settings - therefore I would assume confusing any attempt at getting the coroutine working properly. Thanks everyone for your help though